# gmail html email background color

Tags: html, email

IS there any way to put color as background in HTML email for gmail?

I used this for making body background grey but it doesnt work

```
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#e2e3e7" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
```

Answer (score 33):

Wrap your email in a single celled table with 100% width and height and set the background colour for that cell.

```
<table width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#e2e3e7">

            <!-- "Content" table goes here -->
            <table width="600" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">

            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This was useful, but you have to add width="100%" and height="100%" to the upper <table> too if you want it to fill the e-mail window. So <table width="100%" height="100%">.

Comment: this code is worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

Gmail (and other mailers) remove all css that is not inlined. So the hack of the tables works only because you define the color inline. You don't need a table, instead use

```
<body style="background-color:#242a30;">
```

Comment: While I like this approach better, the generalization that "other mailers" do this is maybe misleading.  I would say _some_ other mail providers do this also.

Comment: Gmail strips every class from body. For Gmail the correct answer is the one from @digout

Answer (score 9):

I just had to do the same thing.   If you put your email body into a table, you can set the table's bgcolor and that will work.

I had `<body bgcolor='lightcyan'>`, then I changed it to `<body> <table bgcolor='lightcyan'>` and put my content into that table.

Answer (score 1):

in most cases you will have a centered email ...
so do this an easy align="center" didnt work for me so i make a width="1680px"

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td width="1680px"  align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e4ebdd">

        <table width='600' align='center' bgcolor='#ffffff'>
        <!-- .... -->

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: No unit (`px`) in width attribute & `bgcolor`, `valign` are deprecated. Last, do not mix single quote with double quote.