# White space on the left & right hand side of a newsletter in gmail

Tags: html, css, gmail, newsletter

I'm creating a newsletter which online [here](http://bombayelectric.in/newsletter/be-newsletter.1.html). But in gmail, on large monitors, there is a lot of whitespace on the left and right hand side of it.

Event though I gave width:100% in the body, the color that I've given to fill is not filled on the outside.

```
<body width="100%" style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;background-color: #f5f4f0;">
```

[image]

What do I have to do to fill the entire space ?

Comment: Seems like the right behavior to me. Text that is too wide can be very difficult to read. I wouldn't bother fighting the existing UI.

Comment: I want the whitespace to be filled with the color #f5f4f0

Comment: That background is the Gmail UI, not your message... only Gmail (or the user if they choose a custom theme) controls the appearance of that area.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gmail html email background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493922/gmail-html-email-background-color)