# Gmail doesn't show background color (html email)

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I'm trying to create an html email that gets sent out to users as a receipt. However I can't get the background-colour to display properly. I've tried putting all the styles inline inside of divs and it still does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height: 0;padding-bottom: 0px;background-color: #d6d6d6;
margin-bottom: 0px; margin: 0 auto;">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Slice Receipt E-mail</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body style="body: 100%;margin: 2%; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top:0px;">
    <div id="white-div" style="body: 100%;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top:0px; background-color: white;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="95%" align="center">
    <tr style="width: 80%">
        <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 15px;">
```

After this I have tables for the e-mail. I don't think it's important to post the next 100+ lines because I think the problem exists in how I'm trying to style it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493922/gmail-html-email-background-color

Comment: My email is already one big table. Are you suggesting I wrap it inside another table?